# Call tap event into iframe

Tags: jquery, reactjs, iframe, jquery-mobile

I’m facing a big problem that I can’t achieve.

I developed an application (app1) with react js. This application will be included with i frame into another application(app2) under the same domain. App2 must access object inside iframe and trigger TAP event ( no click) on a button. Tap event is a custom event of jquery mobile and I think it is used in an old library that couldn’t be changed. I tried in various way but I really don’t know how to solve this problem. Could  web component solve my problem? I can create a web component button with jquery and jquery mobile and include in react app. Can be a solution? Otherwise a think I have to write the application with jquery from scratch.

Comment: use `click` instead, or create a custom event using touch events.

Comment: I can't use click because the library use tap and I can't modify library. 
Is there a way to call trigger('tap') from the external and call click inside iframte?

Answer (score 0):

Can't fully understand Your question, `tap` is just only a name, i.e. You can call it  "singletouch" or whatever You want. Maybe You just only need to find that button inside the `iframe` and add an  `eventListener` to it.

Anyway, if You are including JQM inside Your `iframe`, a `tap` will be recognized by JQM as a sequence of touch events within 750ms on the same target.

Here is the minimal stub to emulate a JQM `tap` :

```
function raiseTap(target) {
  // just only one touch in list is enough
  var tcs = Array(new Touch({
        identifier: Date.now(),
        target: target,
        clientX: 0,
        clientY: 0
      }));

  // emulate a bubbling JQM tap 
  // if needed, add touchmove inbetween
  var events = ["touchstart", "touchend"],
      params = {touches: tcs, bubbles: true, changedTouches: tcs};
  for(var i=0, l=events.length; i<l; i++) {
    target.dispatchEvent(new TouchEvent(events[i], params));
  }
}

// find the target
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe"),
    doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document,
    btn = doc.getElementById("button");

raiseTap(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/jaydson/1780598

```
var myConfObj = {
  iframeMouseOver : false
}
window.addEventListener('blur',function(){
  if(myConfObj.iframeMouseOver){
    console.log('Wow! Iframe Click!');
  }
});

document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){
   myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = true;
});
document.getElementById('YOUR_CONTAINER_ID').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    myConfObj.iframeMouseOver = false;
});
```

Comment: there is no "mouseover", "mouseout" for touch screens